# Search form issues

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to build a search form for on a WP website, and I've been struggling with it for a week now, can't seem to find the right solution.

I have this code now:

```html
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://www.doing-business-international.com/">
<div class="filterbox">
 <div class="search_group1">
    <label class="screen-reader-text-1" for="s">Country</label>
 <input type="text" value="" placeholder="" name="s" id="s" class="text_box_country"/>
</div>
<div class="search_group2">
 <label class="screen-reader-text-2" for="f">Expertise</label>
 <input type="text" value="" placeholder="" name="f" id="f" class="text_box_expertise"/>
</div>
 <div class="search_group3"> 
 <input type="submit" class="btn_double_search" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
 </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I already narrowed the search results down by only letting it search in the titles instead of content aswell.

But it displays all results with the first or second searchword in it, where I want it to display only the results where it has both.

Website is http://www.doing-business-international.com/

I also tried to change the first search box into a dropdown with categories (as all the countries are different categories, but then the outputted search results get really weird:

http://www.doing-business-international.com/test

```html
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://www.doing-business-international.com/">
  <div>
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">In what country do you want to start your business?<br>Which expertise are you looking for?</label><br><br>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_all=Select a country&exclude=1'); ?>
     <input type="text" value="e.g. lawyer" name="s" id="s" class="text_box_expertise"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn_double_search" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

This second search option would was my first idea, but I can't get it to work, so I switched to the search form as it is now on the website.

So ideally, I want a drop-down box with countries (categories) and a type-seach box next to it. So it only searches in the selected categorie.

I am sorry for the long question, but I tried to describe it as good as possible (not really that into coding )

Hope anyone has an idea.

Comment: The two snippets of html are identical? It is the sql that requires attention is it not, rather than the html?

Comment: Yeah, sorry copied the wrong code... edited it now.

Comment: What do you mean bij the sql requires attention? Like I said, I'm not that into coding, I basicly understand what is does (or suposed to do) but can't figure out what to do.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood - though having the correct html helps - but from what I saw the form looks OK. There is the dropdown menu with the country and a text field for the question. From the wording above it seems that it is the results and the subsequent display of results that is the problem not the actual form elements.

Comment: Well... you were right..  It turned out the problem wasn't in the coding after all. Your answer made me look at the page where results are displayed. seems that when I use the search form with two textboxes a different page was used to display the result. When using the search with the category sropdown, results are displayed on a page called archives. (using headway theme) Never thought of that, so thanks!